# System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: Сервер не может обработать запросы каталогов

Tags: c#

**Приветствую всех!**

Пользователь запускает программу на своём компе, проходит доменную авторизацию.

Все его действия должны логироваться. На этапе вызова функции лог-я вылетает исключение:

```
System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: Сервер не может обработать запросы каталогов.
   в System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ErrorChecking.CheckAndSetLdapError(Int32 error)
   в System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapSessionOptions.FastConcurrentBind()
   в System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.BindLdap(NetworkCredential creds, ContextOptions contextOptions)
   в System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.Validate(String userName, String password)
   в System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(String userName, String password)
   в DV.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Данное исключение срабатывает только у тех пользователей, у которых нет прав локального админа.

Проверял на пользователях с правами локального админа, у них все ок.

**Внимание, вопрос:**

Почему программно файлы не создаются, а руками создавать папки и файлы в ОС Windows (через проводник) получается?

Также в `app.manifest` указывал запуск от админа, результат отрицательный.

**Код:**

```
PrincipalContext prCont = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "kakoytodomen.ru");
string pathLog = @"C:\Users\" + SystemInformation.UserName + @"\Documents\dvlog.log"; //Путь к log файлу

//Функция записи в лог (в зависимости от переданного пути).
public void ToLogCommon(string text, string path)
{
    Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
    try
    {
        StreamWriter f_out = new StreamWriter(@"" + path, true, enc);
        f_out.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + " " + text);
        f_out.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

//Кнопка Enter.
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (prCont.ValidateCredentials(textBox1.Text.Trim(), textBox2.Text.Trim()))
        {
            if (IsUserGroupMember(textBox1.Text.Trim(), "DV_DVID"))
            {
                form2.ToLogCommon("Вход выполнен: " + textBox1.Text, form2.pathLog);
                form2.Show();
                this.Opacity = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                form2.ToLogCommon("Данного пользователя: " + textBox1.Text.Trim() + " нет в группе DV_DVID. Доступ запрещён.\r\n", form2.pathLog);
                MessageBox.Show("Доступ запрещён!\r\nДанного пользователя: " + textBox1.Text.Trim() + " нет в группе DV_DVID.\r\nНеобходимо оформить заявку в СПП.", "Предупреждение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            form2.ToLogCommon("Логин или пароль введен неверно! Проверьте правильность введённых данных.\r\n", form2.pathLog);
            MessageBox.Show("Логин или пароль введен неверно!\r\nПроверьте правильность введённых данных.", "Предупреждение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш вариант авторизации не является доменной авторизацией. Это просто LDAP-аутентификация.

Comment: Верно, но не суть. Почему пользователь без админских прав может создавать файлы через проводник, а программно нет? В чем все же проблема? Почему срабатывает исключение при создании файла?

Comment: Нет, суть именно в этом. Проводник использует совершенно другой механизм проверки доступа.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на какой строчке падает - у вас совсем не на этапе создания файла ошибка происходит.

Comment: Удалил свои права локального админа, перезагрузил комп=) Запустил, у меня все пашет) Чудеса... Ошибка соответственно не воспроизводится...)